# Indicate when a flag is by the post owner

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, moderator-tools, waffle-bar

Can the moderator flag bar be changed to indicate when a flag is by the owner of the flagged post? It could be the same as how comments by the post owner are indicated, or some other way.

#### Before

[image]

#### After

[image]

Comment: Your before and after shots are the same.

Comment: @Danny No they're not. The blue OP background is just really hard to see on the grey background behind it.

Comment: It is hard to see at first, normally that style is used on a white background, but I think it's clear once you know what to look for. But that's why I said "or some other way"; I don't really care what the difference is

Comment: I don't understand why this can be helpfull. Can you please clarify why do you want that.

Comment: @Mhmd Frequently the post owner will flag asking that the post be closed/deleted/migrated/whatever

Comment: @animuson, perhaps you could add the status-completed tag, as per answer from Glorfindel

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature has been introduced with the [new flag dashboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328838/moderator-flag-dashboard-design-refresh-alpha/329141#comment1076017_329141); the flag bar shows [question owner] or [answer owner] when appropriate:

[image]