# Disable option to opt in new mod tools on other user preference page if this user isn't a mod

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, preferences

If I open preferences page of another user I can see option to opt [in a new mod tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328838/260198).

> [image]

But this user isn't mod. Probable, on this page the engine checks **my** account status, but should check **this user** status, and display this option depending on it.

Comment: Now I want to know what happens if you opt that user in...

Comment: @Laurel this user will not get access to mod tools, if you asking about this. I've tried (:

Comment: It'd really help if you add these as answers to Brian's question so that he's directly notified. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328838/284336

Comment: @Catija done https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329262/260198 ^_^

Comment: Thanks!  I don't think we're planning to keep this in testing very long so fixing this may not be a priority. We'll see what he says.