# Could the moderator flag dashboard have an indicator if a post is in the review queue?

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, review, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

<sub>This comes from [Moderator flag dashboard design refresh (alpha)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/328838/209901) when I posted an answer and was asked to move it to a different question.</sub>

Suppose an old answer gets flagged as *Not an answer* or *Very low quality*. If it did not get any of these flags in the past, now it will enter in the Low quality posts review queue. Otherwise, it will not and the flag will have to get resolved by the mods.

In general, it is preferable if community handles the flags, but the old and new dashboards don't show if there is a review item for a given flagged post. This way, it is easy for a mod to just go ahead and resolve the flag without knowing that some users could/were handling it already. However, it is a pity to intervene if the community was already doing so.

Nowadays, one can navigate to the post, check its timeline and, just there, see if there is any open review item. Too many clicks for some information that is quite useful.

For this: **could the moderator flag dashboard have an indicator on whether a post is in the review queue?**