# Moderator Flag Dashboard hard launch

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

> **Previous posts**
>
> - [Moderator Flag Dashboard soft launch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330171/moderator-flag-dashboard-soft-launch)
> - [Moderator flag dashboard design refresh (alpha)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328838/moderator-flag-dashboard-design-refresh-alpha)

As of today, the Moderator Flag Dashboard is officially graduated and the old version sent to the smelter's yard.

Based on stats from the past month, virtually all moderators were already on the new UI (thank you) so you hopefully won't notice any change.  That said, I would like to highlight the handful of improvements we made over the last month and a half based on your feedback:

- A more responsive navigation bar at the top of moderator pages, improving the mobile experience.
- Similarly, [tightened up vertical spacing on narrow (mobile) viewports](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330171/moderator-flag-dashboard-soft-launch/330261#330261), increasing room on the screen for the first question.
- [Brought back reputation when relevant to the flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330245/the-new-flag-dashboard-doesnt-include-the-reputation-of-the-user-whose-post-is).
- [Fixed and enhanced post and comment links in the waffle bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330181/do-the-hash-linking-like-before).  Not only do the headers look better, they now function better.  Now you scroll to and highlight the post/comment each time you click the link, not just the first time.
- [Improved sorting when looking at the Duplicate answers flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330211/the-duplicate-answers-flags-are-harder-to-process-in-the-new-dashboard).  Posts by the same user are grouped together and ordered newest first.
- [Improved the auto-flag dismiss experience](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330180/allow-us-to-decline-the-automatically-raised-flags).  We eliminated the VLQ (auto) side effect so now "Resolve all flags (auto)" doesn't do anything surprising.  If you still want to leave a comment or decline, you can do so with the buttons next to the individual flags.

### Bugs and Feature Requests

Since this project is officially launched, all bugs and feature requests should be done in the form of questions tagged [flag-dashboard](/questions/tagged/flag-dashboard) on MSE, *not* answers on this post.  Feel free to post an answer here if you have specific concerns about the release process.

Comment: Would be nice, if you find time to look on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330885/260198) also  ^_^".