# The new flag dashboard doesn't include the reputation of the user whose post is being flagged

Tags: support, status-completed, not-an-answer, flag-dashboard

Having the reputation of the user whose post is being flagged is a useful piece of information - especially for "not an answer" flags. If the user has less than 50 rep - i.e. a new user - then they are less likely to know the rules that govern when you can post a comment.

For an established user simple deletion would suffice, but for a new user you might want to leave a follow up comment explaining why the non-answer was deleted and encouraging them to participate enough to be able to comment.

Please can you add the user's reputation to the information on the dashboard.

[image]

Comment: I think [this request of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328863/255554) is responsible for this, though I also suggested to show this information in a pop-up (like on the regular user interface), which I think should is a good trade-off between making the information quickly available for the cases you describe and not cluttering the interface otherwise. I would certainly consider the reputation more relevant than the joining date.

Comment: I think "not an answer" flags should motivate mods to actually look at the answer, and not judge solely or primarily at the answerer's rep.  I.e., I think showing a a flagged user's rep allows too much for unintentional bias against the flagged answer (in the case that the user has low rep) and in favor of flagged answers (in cases in which the answerer has high rep).

Comment: @JedrekMansfield we do. But if it clearly reads like a comment (which most do) then knowing the reputation of the poster will help us decide what to do.

Comment: Fwiw, we do have an idea for adding this as a pop-up along with other user info; gonna take a bit for that though.

Comment: @ChrisF  "Most" low-rep users' answers read like comments?  How do you interpret "most"?  I'd agree that many such posts *do* read like comments.  But when one becomes cynical (AND is a MOD) who starts describing *most* of such answers read like comments, then you've lost me, and hence, I suspect, there is *some* degree of cynicism and bias in your use of *most*.  Most to me is like 80%; most exceeds "the majority".  When you use such ambiguous and ambivalent claims, it only reinforces my points here.  And *many* high-rep users post only comments as answers.

Comment: @JedrekMansfield what I mean is that most of the "things posted in the answer box" that flagged as "not an answer" read like comments. With questions as a close second.

Comment: I'd agree, @ChrisF  But I still don't see why dealing with such flags requires having available the answerer's rep.  Read each answer that is flagged as NAN.  Does it read like a comment, in your opinion as a mod? If yes, take action.  If no, then decline action.  I just don't see how "knowing in advance what the answerer's rep is" is a sound reason to shortcut one's decision.  (If one reads the answer, one will see the answerers rep, No?)

Comment: @JedrekMansfield That action will depend on the reputation of the poster. > 50 and it can be just converted to a comment or deleted. < 50 and we might want to follow up after the deletion. If I can do all that without leaving the flag queue then, especially on SO, that's what I want to do.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks @ChrisF.  I did not know that last detail.  Now *that* makes a valid difference in terms of knowing how best to act.  Thanks for reading my comments and following up, and clarifying!  I clearly misunderstood your request to know the rep of an answerer's post flagged as NAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

We will show reputation and joined date as a unit based on the following logic:

1. If the post owner received any post flags.
2. If the post owner received a flag on a comment they'd posted.
3. If the post owner raised a flag on their own post or a comment on that post.

Basically, if the owner is involved with the flagged content, you'll see their stats, otherwise you won't.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question but why only display then?  Wouldn't a mod want to see a user's rep *all of the time???*

Comment: @Fabby Apparently not.  There have been complaints about too much noise on the page, and there are some legitimate cases where that rep is irrelevant.  If Alice writes a post, Bob writes an unwelcoming comment on it, and Charlie flags the comment, you *shouldn't* need to see Alice's reputation when making a moderation decision.