# Collapse post after flagging it as spam from the moderator flag dashboard

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, spam, flag-dashboard

When deleting a post with the 'delete' menu link from the 'mini post UI' in the new ♦ moderator flag dashboard, the dashboard collapses the post. This was a result of implementing [one of my feature requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329173/295232) and I really appreciate it.

This morning, I encountered a post flagged as spam in the flag dashboard, and it was spam; so I opened the 'mini post UI' and flagged it as such. I expected the dashboard to collapse the post, but it didn't. Can this behaviour be implemented here as well? If I remember correctly, the old dashboard sort-of did - it moved the post to a list of resolved flags at the top of the dashboard.