# More options than "delete" and "decline" when handling comment flags

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

I'm expanding this from a [feature-request previously posted as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328868/278659), as requested by [dev Brian Nickel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel) back in June. (Yeah, late to the party, I know. Maybe they've even stopped working on improving the new mod dashboard now. Anyway.)

In the new moderator dashboard, flags on **posts** can either be marked helpful or declined. Clicking on "helpful ..." or "decline ..." gives us the option to enter a custom reason for the flagging user to see. There's also a button to delete the post directly, which automatically marks the flag helpful:

[image: buttons for post flag]

However, for flags on **comments** we have far less options: it's just "delete", "edit", and "decline". There's no natural way to mark a comment flag helpful without deleting or editing the comment (the only workaround is to delete the comment and immediately undelete it, or make a null edit to it). There's no way to give feedback to the flagger on a comment flag, not even canned reasons to explain why it was declined.

---

I know comments are third-class citizens and all, but does the comment flag process need to be so basic? Would it be difficult to **use the same code for comment flags as for post flags**, giving mods the option to provide custom decline feedback or to mark a flag as helpful without just hitting the delete button?

To counter the counterpoints raised in comments on [my previous answer-FR](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328868/278659):

- This change would waste zero mod time in cases where you just want to delete stuff: if there's a red "delete" button like for posts, you can hit that and bypass the helpful/decline dichotomy.
- It (presumably) wouldn't require much extra design in terms of how the tools would actually work, because it's the same thing you're already doing for post flags.

Comment: This would greatly help in educating users in what cases it is appropriate to flag something!

Comment: I'm pretty sure comment flags now also have the "Decline and Delete" option (though that doesn't address your concerns).