# Destroying an account deletes its comments but leaves flags on those comments pending

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, comment-flags, account-destruction

Just now, a comment flag on the site I moderate brought my attention to a troll account, which I accordingly destroyed. Account destruction automatically deleted the comment, as expected (although it left an annoying "show 1 more comment" which won't go away), but it **didn't dismiss the flag on the now-deleted comment**, which means I now *can't* mark the flag helpful without making an unnecessary edit to the comment.

[image]

The comment is "*deleted by Anonymous 6 mins ago*", but the flag still shows as pending. There is no "Delete" option to handle the flag, because the comment is already gone. I don't want to decline it, because it was helpful. The only remaining option is to edit the comment unnecessarily - which I'm going to do, but this seems like a silly bug.

Related: [More options than "delete" and "decline" when handling comment flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337731/278659)